# Issue related to handler desing pattern

Tags: android, event-handling, handler

I have one class in which a listener is implemented and depending on the methods call in listener, I am to update the data in corresponding activities. For this, i am interested in using the different-different handlers for each activity.
Since, my handler class in each activity is static and hence, handler object is non-static in activity.
So, problem is how to use those activity's handlers to send Message to them.? Help?

This is one of my class in which I am to update the data from another class: How to do?

```
public class HandlerActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
int counter;
Handler handler = new HandlerExtension(this);


//handler static class
private static class HandlerExtension extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<HandlerActivity> targetActivity;
    //constructor
    HandlerExtension(HandlerActivity activity){
        this.targetActivity = new WeakReference<HandlerActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        HandlerActivity activity = targetActivity.get();

        if(activity != null){
            final String data = msg.getData().getString("counter");//gettting msg data
            activity.tv.setText(data);
        }
    }
}//HandlerExtension


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.handler_activity);
    Button startB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {//object to be executed in the thread
        @Override
        public void run() {
            counter+=10;
            String result = String.valueOf(counter);
            Message msg = new Message();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("counter", result);
            msg.setData(bundle);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);//Now, updating the view from background thread via handler

            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
    };

    //starting the background thread on button click
    startB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    });




}//onCreate
```

}//HandlerActivity

Comment: @blackbelt I want to send the Message in the above activity Message queue via handler. Can you tell how to send Message in this activity from another class.

Comment: you can not. Why do you need and Handler?

Comment: In a chat app, when the packet arrives, depending to the packet type I am to send these to the corresponding activities.

Comment: you have a bunch  of opportunities. I think that something like services and broadcast receive are better for this purpose